# displaying rss feed with php pagination

Tags: php, rss, pagination, feed

I'm new to rss feeds and php pagination. I'm trying to parse rss feed and display each feed details on separate pages. I copied and pasted the pagination code from http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html. When i run index.php on localhost, nothing gets displayed.

I have no problem downloading the rss feed using curl. I have also tried print_r($data) and data is displaying fine.

Can someone point me on where i'm going wrong? thank you.

my code:

```
<?php
if (function_exists("curl_init")){
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://feeds.feedburner.com/rb286");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $data=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $doc=new SimpleXmlElement($data);
    //print_r($doc);
}

function parseRSS($xml){
    $items=$xml->xPath('/rss/channels/item');

    $count=count($items);

    // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
    $adjacents =3;


    $total_pages = $count;

    /* Setup vars for query. */
    $targetpage = "index.php";  //your file name  (the name of this file)
    $limit = 1;                                 //how many items to show per page
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
    else
        $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0


    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

    /* 
        Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
    */
    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">� previous</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">� previous</span>"; 

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next �</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next �</span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
    }

        foreach($items as $item){
              echo("<a href='".$item[0]->link."'>".$item[0]->title."</a>");
        }
}
if (isset($doc->channel))parseRSS($doc);

?>
<?php 
 echo($pagination);
?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so there are some issues with this code :

First the variable `$pagination;` is created within the function and therefor not available outside in the global scope. the quick fix for this is :

At the beginning of the page add :

```
<?php 
$pagination = '';
```

Inside the function add :

```
function parseRSS($xml){
    global $pagination;
```

**Next the Xpath location is wrong**

change :

```
$items=$xml->xPath('/rss/channels/item');
```

into

```
$items=$xml->xPath('/rss/channel/item');
```

These changes should give you some output to get started, i think there are more issues with your pagination but you should manage to sort it out once you have some output.

**EDIT :** 
To get only the needed link you should change :

```
<?php  
foreach($items as $item){
    echo("<a href='".$item[0]->link."'>".$item[0]->title."</a>");
}
```

into :

```
<?php  
foreach($items as $key => $item){
    if( ( $key >= $start) && ($key < $start + $limit) ){
        echo("<a href='".$item[0]->link."'>".$item[0]->title."</a>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that did help out. At least the links are getting displayed. Do you know what is the purpose of $adjacents=3? What does it mean by "// How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?"?

Comment: adjacents probably means if, for example you are on page 5, then the pagination will be `2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8` but that's just a guess, only way to find out is change it and see what happens.

Comment: adjacents just calculates how the pagination object's page numbers 1|2|3|4|...is going to be displayed.

Comment: Now, i'm not able to display one link in each page. All the links are getting displayed on all pages. After displaying the first link, how can I get the foreach loop to go to the next page and display the next link? this could be done easily if i was using a database table using the limit keyword. But here i'm using RSS feed.

Comment: How can I set the link limit for each page using xml and xpath?

Comment: I mean how can i set the limit for xpath queries?

Answer (score 0):

DonSeba, your 2nd foreach loop works fine. Each link is displaying well on a different page. However, can you please tell me what is the purpose of your if statement with 2 conditions?
I tried out the following with only 1 if condition and it works fine too:

```
foreach($items as $key => $item){ 
//if( ( $key >= $start) && ($key < $start + $limit) ){ //your if statement
  if ($key==$start){
    echo("<a href='".$item[0]->link."'>".$item[0]->title."</a>"); 
     } 
 }
```

thank you.