# PHP - How to read RSS feeds with limit ( Pagination )

Tags: php, xml, rss

I know there are a lot of ways to read RSS in php just like

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss');
var_dump($rss);
```

and when I am searching for paginate the feeds and limit them by offset as any pagination example I found more than one way just like

- [displaying rss feed with php pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574231/displaying-rss-feed-with-php-pagination)
- http://www.phpexpertsforum.com/display-rss-feeds-with-pagination-using-php-t2173.html
- http://bavotasan.com/2010/display-rss-feed-with-php/

all of them paginate the feeds after getting all of them form rss provider

my question is

"Is there any way to read the RSS feeds in paging way like [twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines) or [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/) APIs?"

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: It depends on the feed service.

Comment: there is no way to work on all RSS provider ,  standard or protocol I wanna develop generic module reader with pagination facility  

if not how can i know is it available or not 

http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss

Comment: Well if the service has no pagination facility, you fetch everything then you slice it via PHP. If you are concerned with RSS payload, use some reverse-proxy mechanism.

Comment: Really , I don't know RSS payload and reverse-proxy mechanism I am searching for them now but if you have any code snippet it will be more than appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no generic way to do this will work with all providers - what they give you in response to your requests is up to them. Some can/will paginate, others won't - as you've discovered; most won't - they'll just give you back the RSS feed as is.

If you're trying to create a generic module, then it will need to be able to handle paginated feeds if it gets one. It will also either need to keep a white-list of providers which give you paginated feeds or learn to recognise paginated feeds when it receives them - and handle them appropriately.

There are lots of open source RSS readers/aggregators around who's source code you could look at for examples - http://tt-rss.org/redmine/projects/tt-rss/wiki is popular and written in PHP - you could look and see how they do it?

Comment: Thanks a lot my dear I am gonna use some reverse-proxy mechanism as @moonwave99 comment.. thanks again and again